# File parser convert to node data and neighbouring relational data

Tags: python, beginner, parsing

I have been working on a file parser that takes a very specific file format and parses it into a list that is arranged into node data and the neighbors that it relates to. I am new to Python (this is my very first program in this language), so I am not familiar with more advanced methods of solving the problem using Python.

The program runs very quickly: I get an average of about `Elapsed time: 0.0006923562137193841` with a test file, but think it could be even better, especially if I task it with a significantly larger file.

**Seeking from question:**

1. Optimization in the form of cleaner methods
2. Decrease the overall runtime
3. Verification of estimated runtime: \$O(N * E)\$. I got this because there are `N` nodes, which each contain `E` edges. However, this may or may not be incorrect.
4. General style comments for Python coding

**Input file example:**

The following would be 1 line of data in the file. This file could contain thousands of lines, each line identifying a node and the neighbors that it has.

```
100  Alpha  123  321  ((101,Beta,123,321)(101,Gamma,123,321)(102,Alpha,123,321)(103,Alpha,123,321)(104,Beta,123,321)(105,Alpha,123,321)(099,Gamma,123,321)(098,Beta,123,321)(097,Beta,123,321)(222,Gamma,123,321)(223,Beta,123,321)(234,Gamma,123,321)(451,Beta,123,321)(999,Beta,123,321)(879,Gamma,123,321)(369,Gamma,123,321)(741,Beta,123,321)(753,Beta,123,321)(357,Beta,123,321)(159,Alpha,123,321))
```

The parsing would end with the line containing only `"At the last row"`.

```
import os
import timeit

__author__ = 'Evan Bechtol'

"""
Parses through a file given the appropriate filepath. Once a filepath
has been received, the Parser instance opens and begins parsing out the
individual nodes and their neighbor node relationships. Each node is an
index of the nodeList, which contains a sub-list of the nodes that are neighbors
of that node.

The structure is created as follows:
nodeList: A list that is 'n' nodes long. The sub-list containing neighbors is of
          length 'e', where 'e' is the number of neighbor-edges.

numNeighbors: A list that contains the number of neighbors for each node from 0 to (n-1)

Resulting runtime of class: O(N*E)
"""
class Parser:

    # Constructor accepting filepath for file to read
    # as am argument. The constructor also calls readFile with
    # the filepath to begin parsing the specific file.
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        self.nodeList     = []
        self.numNeighbors = []
        self.readFile(filePath)

    # Add nodes the the nodeList in order that they appear
    def setNodeData(self, id, sector, freq, band, neighborList):
        tmpData = ((id), (sector), (freq), (band), (neighborList))
        return tmpData


    # Add neighbors to the neighborList in the order that they appear
    def setNeighborData(self, id, sector, freq, band):
        tmpData = ((id), (sector), (freq), (band))
        return tmpData

    # Returns the entire nodeList as a string
    def getNodeList(self):
        return str(self.nodeList)

    # Return a specific node of the nodeList with all of its' neighbors
    def getNodeListIndex(self, index):
        return str(self.nodeList[index])

    # Return a specific neighbor for a given node
    def getNodeNeighbor(self, node, neighbor):
        return str(self.nodeList[node][4][neighbor])


    # Retrieves the location of the line to begin retrieving node and
    # neighbor data in the file. This eliminates any data above the actual
    # data required to build node and neighbor relationships.
    def searchForStartLine(self, data):
        startLine = "-default-  -  -  -  -  "
        numLines  = 0

        for line in data:
            numLines += 1
            if startLine in line:
                return numLines


    # Removes parenthesis from the line so that neighbors can be parsed.
    # Returns the line with all parenthesis removed and individual neighbors
    # are separated by spaces.
    def removeParens(self, line):
        # First, remove all parenthesis
        line = line.strip("((")
        line = line.strip("))")
        line = line.replace(")(", " ")
        return line



    # Splits the provided line into the required sections for
    # placement into the appropriate lists.
    # The reference node is parsed first and stored into the nodeList
    #
    # Once the nodeList is updated, the neighbor data is then parsed from
    # the line and stored in the neighborList for the reference node.
    def splitLine(self, line):
        # Separate into individual reference nodes
        splitLine = line.split()
        line = self.extractNode(line, splitLine)




    # Get each individual node from the specific line. This is referred to as the
    # "reference node", which represents the node that we will be creating a specific
    # list of neighbors for.
    # Each reference node is unique and contains a unique neighborList.
    def extractNode(self, line, splitLine):
        # Get all of the node data first and store in the nodeList
        nodeId = splitLine[0]
        sector = splitLine[1]
        freq   = splitLine[2]
        band   = splitLine[3]
        line   = self.removeParens(splitLine[4])

        # Separate into individual neighbors
        neighbor = line.split()

        # Contains the number of neighbors for each reference node
        self.numNeighbors.append(len(neighbor))

        # Place each neighbor tuple into the neighborList
        neighborList = self.extractNeighbors(neighbor)

        self.nodeList.append(self.setNodeData(nodeId, sector, freq, band, neighborList))
        return line

    # Get the parsed list of neighbors for all nodes, then append
    # them to the neighborList in order that they are read.
    def extractNeighbors(self, neighbor):
        # Create a temporary storage for the neighbors of the reference node
        neighborList = []

        # Separate each neighbor string into individual neighbor components
        for i in range(len(neighbor)):
            neighbor[i] = neighbor[i].replace(",", " ")
            neighbor[i] = neighbor[i].split()
            nodeId = neighbor[i][0]
            sector = neighbor[i][1]
            freq   = neighbor[i][2]
            band   = neighbor[i][3]

            # Append the components to the neighborList
            neighborList.append(self.setNeighborData(nodeId, sector, freq, band))
        return neighborList


    # Read the file and remove junk data, leaving only the node and neighbor
    # data behind for storage in the data structure
    def readFile(self, fileName):
        # Check if the file exists at the specified path
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print ('File does not exist.')

        # File exists, will attempt parsing
        else:
            with open(str(fileName)) as file:
                data = file.readlines()

                # Look for the first sign of data that we can use, read from that location
                currentLine = self.searchForStartLine(data)

                # Read from file until we find the last line of data that we need
                lastLine = "At the last row"
                for line in data:
                    if lastLine in data[currentLine + 1]:
                        break
                    else:
                        nodeId = data[0]
                        self.splitLine(data[currentLine])
                        currentLine += 1
                return file.read()

# Read file, given the exact file path
startTime = timeit.timeit()
parse = Parser("<file_path>")

#print(parse.getNodeNeighbor(1, 0))
print (parse.nodeList[0][4][0])

endTime = timeit.timeit()

print ("Elapsed time: " + str(endTime - startTime))
```

Comment: As a side note, I just read another question here on the site and have discovered that using """ to indicate comments is generally considered bad practice. :)

Comment: Rule of thumb: 80% of the execution time is spent in 20% of the code. To do meaningful optimizations, use [a profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to measure the time that's spent inside each of your functions. Test your code on a large data set. The performance for a small file doesn't matter. Use empirical studies to verify your estimated runtime. Measure the running time multiple times for different values of N and E and analyze the result.

Comment: I notice your `readFile` checks for a file's existence and then simply prints a message if it can't find it. It's not really a style issue, but as a potential user of your Parser class, I think I would expect it to at least throw an exception in that case. You could bypess the existence check altogether and just let `open` throw an exception for you if it can't be opened. By the way, a file not existing is only one of the reasons a file could fail to be opened. See also "EAFP" in the Python glossary.

Comment: @Brandin I had the print statement there for testing purposes. Once I put this code into production similar print statements (including the one mentioned) were replaced with exceptions that are then displayed in a GUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Style

- Use `snake_case` for functions and variables.
- Leave 1 line between methods.
- Don't overwrite keywords, `id`, `file`. Use synonyms or `id_`, the former is preferred.
- Keep lines to a maximum of 79. (Comments should be a maximum of 72 however.)
- Avoid excessive white-space.
- Use one space between both sides of the assignment operator. E.G. `a = 1`, not `a  = 1`.

As @Quill said docstrings are good.
And you should write them instead of *some* of your comments in your code.

## Algorithms

`setNodeData` Can be shortened to just:

```
def setNodeData(self, id_, sector, freq, band, neighborList):
    return ((id_), (sector), (freq), (band), (neighborList))
```

---

`searchForStartLine` should use the builtin enumerate.

```
def searchForStartLine(self, data):
    start_line = "-default-  -  -  -  -  "
    for line_num, line in enumerate(data):
        if start_line in line:
            return line_num
```

---

`splitLine` is only used once. Also you overwrite `line` and don't use it after the overwrite.
Consider removing it.

---

`extractNeighbors` can be simplified to a list comprehension, and *could* be simpler that way.
It is also faster than appending to an existing list.

I first used the `*` operator on the slice `[:4]`. This way you don't have to define `sector`, etc.
I then removed the need for `i`, there is no need for it, as everything uses `neighbor[i]`.

```
def extractNeighbors(self, neighbors):
    return [
            self.setNeighborData(
                *(neighbor.replace(",", " ").split()[:4])
            )
            for neighbor in neighbors
            ]
```

---

We can do roughly the same thing above to `extractNode`, to minimise code.

First remove all the noise of `sector` etc. We will use `*(splitLine[:5])`.
You only make changes to `splitLine[4]`, and the other informaton just clutters that.

```
def extractNode(self, splitLine):
    splitLine[4] = self.extractNeighbors(
        self.removeParens(splitLine[4]).split()
        )
    self.numNeighbors.append(len(splitLine[4]))
    self.nodeList.append(self.setNodeData(*(splitLine[:5])))
```

---

In `readFile` you should change the for loop.

```
for line in data:
```

You don't use `line`, and you do `currentLine += 1`.

```
for line_num, _ in enumerate(data, currentLine):
    if lastLine in data[line_num + 1]:
        break
    else:
        nodeId = data[0]
        self.splitLine(data[line_num])
```

It may be better to use `range` however.

---

Overall, this will have no effect on the speed.
But it highlights that `str.split` and `str.replace` are probably the reasons that it is slow.
This is as they are, if I recall correctly, linear time.
You could try using the optional argument of `str.split`, maxsplit, to not go through the entire string.
And you wouldn't need to use `[:4]` and `[:5]`.

The only other way I can see speeding this up would be to use a different algorithm to handle each line in roughly O(n).
I know that we aren't allowed to write compleat rewrites so [here](http://pastebin.com/E4Lnpy83) is an example I wrote.

---

1. There are no speed optimisations.
2. Same as 1. But try `str.split`'s maxsplit.
3. I can't comment.
4. It's throughout.

Comment: Feel free to add the rewrite to the answer. It's just that posting **only** a rewrite without commenting on the original code would not be a good answer. [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/complete-code-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code per the suggestions given in Joe Wallis' answer.

I have changed the main loop in the `readFile` method, eliminating the if/else statements. I have also added additional methods to aid in easily retrieving data later form a separate module that is used.

```
import os
import time

__author__ = 'Evan Bechtol'

"""
Parses through a file given the appropriate filepath. Once a filepath
has been received, the Parser instance opens and begins parsing out the
individual nodes and their neighbor node relationships. Each node is an
index of the nodeList, which contains a sub-list of the nodes that are neighbors
of that node.

The structure is created as follows:
nodeList: A list that is 'n' nodes long. The sub-list containing neighbors is of
          length 'e', where 'e' is the number of neighbor-vertices.

numNeighbors: A list that contains the number of neighbors for each node from 0 to (n-1)

Resulting runtime of class: O(N*E)
"""
class Parser:
    # Constructor accepting filepath for file to read
    # as am argument. The constructor also calls readFile with
    # the filepath to begin parsing the specific file.
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        self.nodeList     = []
        self.numNeighbors = []
        self.readFile(filePath)

    # Add nodes the the nodeList in order that they appear
    def setNodeData(self, id, sector, freq, band, neighborList):
        return ((id), (sector), (freq), (band), (neighborList))

    # Add neighbors to the neighborList in the order that they appear
    def setNeighborData(self, id, sector, freq, band):
        return ((id), (sector), (freq), (band))

    # Returns the entire nodeList as a string
    def getNodeList(self):
        return str(self.nodeList)

    # Return a specific node of the nodeList with all of its' neighbors
    def getNodeListIndex(self, index):
        return str(self.nodeList[index])

    # Returns a list of neighbors represented by a string, for a given node.
    # Each index of the list is an individual neighbor of that node.
    def getNodeNeighborList(self, node):
        neighborString = []
        i = 0
        while i < self.numNeighbors[node]:
            neighborString.append(self.getNodeNeighbor(node, i))
            i += 1
        return neighborString

    # Return a specific neighbor for a given node
    def getNodeNeighbor(self, node, neighbor):
        return str(self.nodeList[node][4][neighbor][0] + "_" + \
                   self.nodeList[node][4][neighbor][1] + "_" + \
                   self.nodeList[node][4][neighbor][2] + "_" + \
                   self.nodeList[node][4][neighbor][3])

    # Returns the node information, as a string, for a given index on the
    # nodeList.
    # Data is returned as follows:
    # NodeID_Sector_Frequency_Band
    def getNode(self, node):
        return (self.nodeList[node][0] + "_" + \
                self.nodeList[node][1] + "_" + \
                self.nodeList[node][2] + "_" + \
                self.nodeList[node][3])

    # Return the NodeID for a given index on the nodeList
    def getNodeId(self, node):
        return (self.nodeList[node][0])

    # Returns the number of nodes in the nodeList
    def getNumNodes(self):
        return (len(self.nodeList) + 1)

    # Returns the number of neighbors that exist for a given node as an int
    def getNodeNumNeighbors(self, node):
        return self.numNeighbors[node]

    # Retrieves the location of the line to begin retrieving node and
    # neighbor data in the file. This eliminates any data above the actual
    # data required to build node and neighbor relationships.
    def searchForStartLine(self, data):
        startLine = "-default-  -  -  -  -  "
        numLines  = 0

        for line in data:
            numLines += 1
            if startLine in line:
                return numLines

    # Removes parenthesis from the line so that neighbors can be parsed.
    # Returns the line with all parenthesis removed and individual neighbors
    # are separated by spaces.
    def removeParens(self, line):
        # First, remove all parenthesis
        line = line.strip("((")
        line = line.strip("))")
        line = line.replace(")(", " ")
        return line

    # Get each individual node from the specific line.
    # This is referred to as the "reference node",
    # which represents the node that we will be creating a specific
    # list of neighbors for.
    # Each reference node is unique and contains a unique neighborList.
    def extractNode(self, splitLine):
        splitLine[4] = self.extractNeighbors(
            self.removeParens(splitLine[4]).split()
            )
        self.numNeighbors.append(len(splitLine[4]))
        self.nodeList.append(self.setNodeData(*(splitLine[:5])))

    # Get the parsed list of neighbors for all nodes, then append
    # them to the neighborList in order that they are read.
    def extractNeighbors(self, neighbors):
        return [
                self.setNeighborData(
                    *(neighbor.replace(",", " ").split()[:4])
                )
                for neighbor in neighbors
                ]

    # Read the file and remove junk data, leaving only the node and neighbor
    # data behind for storage in the data structure
    def readFile(self, fileName):
        # Check if the file exists at the specified path
        if not os.path.isfile(fileName):
            print ('File does not exist.')

        # File exists, will attempt parsing
        else:
            with open(str(fileName)) as file:
                data = file.readlines()

                # Look for the first sign of data that we can use, read from that location
                currentLine = self.searchForStartLine(data)

                # Read from file until we find the last line of data that we need
                lastLine = "At the last row"
                while lastLine not in data[currentLine + 1]:
                    nodeId = data[0]
                    self.extractNode(data[currentLine].split())
                    currentLine += 1
```

Comment: Don't forget to reward the best answer by accepting it if it helped you improve your code.

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted

Comment: @Phrancis my bad :( Not really sure why someone would downvote and not explain why.

Comment: No worries friend